# Using PHP to select rows between dates through variables

Tags: php, mysql, pdo

I'm trying to fetch all rows where the date column's value is a day in july using the code below:

```
$july="07";
$query=$conn->prepare("SELECT * FROM table WHERE date BETWEEN '2018-?-01' AND '2018-?-31'");
$query->execute($july,$july);
$row=$query->setFetchMode();
```

I have also tried like this:

```
$july="07";
$month_1="'2018-".$july."-01'";
$month_2="'2018-".$july."-31'";

$query=$conn->prepare("SELECT * FROM table WHERE date BETWEEN ? AND ?");
$query->execute(array($month_1,$month_2));
$row=$query->setFetchMode();
```

1st case, I get the following error:

**Fatal error: Uncaught exception 'PDOException' with message 'SQLSTATE[HY093]: Invalid parameter number: number of bound variables does not match number of tokens' in file.php on line 35**

I assume I get that error because I cannot have '?' in a query between single brackets.

Second case, I get nothing at all.

Solved it with this:

```
SELECT * FROM table WHERE YEAR(date)=2018 AND MONTH(date)=?
```

Comment: Remove the nested quotes from your `$month_1` and `$month_2` variables, ie `$momth_1 = "2018-$july-01";`. Voting to close as a typo

Comment: You are correct about your 1st case; you cannot interpolate placeholders into strings in your query

Comment: ... or even `MONTH(date) = ? and YEAR(date) = ?` with `7` and `2018` bound respectively

Comment: Thanks @Phil, I figured it out. The actual issue was that I was not able to use "?" between quotes. So the final solution was this: SELECT * FROM table WHERE MONTH(date)=? AND DAY(date) BETWEEN 01 AND 31

Comment: What about July dates in years other than 2018? Your query will also match those. The `DAY` comparison is completely redundant too

Comment: Right, 4 AM here. Fixed it. Thanks for all the help.

Comment: Seeing `$july` as a variable is a bit of overkill. Having single-use variables is also a bit of a mess. Just use an array: `$query->execute([ '2018-07-01', '2018-07-31' ])` is more than enough.

Answer (score 2):

Query 1 fails because you can't quote a placeholder.

Query 2 fails because the single quotes get escaped by the driver and then the whole escaped string gets wrapped in quotes. Roughly

```
date BETWEEN '\'2018-07-01\''
```

There are a few ways you could accomplish this.

Take the first 7 values of your date column and compare that against your string.

```
$date = '2018-07';
...then execute the query like ...
WHERE substr(date, 1, 7) = ?
```

You also could use the `concat` method which keeps the placeholder from being quoted.

```
$july="07";
$query=$conn->prepare("SELECT * FROM table WHERE date BETWEEN concat('2018-', ?, '-01') AND concat('2018-', ?, '-31')");
$query->execute(array($july, $july));
$row=$query->setFetchMode();
```

Comment: Why is this syntax not in the documentation?  Does this work?  sending two variables as parameter?   Pretty sure it will throw an error.   `$query->execute($july,$july);`

Comment: @BrianPatterson Yea, it would. That was copied from the question. Based on the provided error we know that wasn't there actual code though. I'll update the answer.

Answer (score -2):

First case error is because you passed two variables to PDO::execute() and its expecting array there.

Suggested Reading...

http://php.net/manual/en/pdostatement.execute.php

Second case .. ummm..  you sure it does nothing?

```
Select * from mytable where date <= '2018-07-31' and date >= '2018-07-01'
```

or whatever...   this maybe ...

```
select * from mytable where date between UNIX_TIMESTAMP(STR_TO_DATE('Jul 01 2018 12:00AM', '%M %d %Y %h:%i%p')) and UNIX_TIMESTAMP(STR_TO_DATE('Jul 31 2018 11:59PM', '%M %d %Y %h:%i%p'))
```

Never use * to return all columns in a table–it’s lazy. You should only extract the data you need. Even if you require every field, your tables will inevitably change.   -https://www.sitepoint.com/mysql-mistakes-php-developers/

Comment: @LemnaruEduard-Mihai You don't need the `day` you should use `YEAR` though. I don't like the date functions because they bypass indexes.

Comment: `BETWEEN` does exactly the same thing as your query

Comment: The question is clearly PDO-based. Suggesting `mysqli` is a huge step backwards, and it's even more reckless and irresponsible to paste in this gigantic blob of code I can only describe as **EXTREMELY HAZARDOUS**. Please delete that part before someone gets hurt by it. `mysql_escape_string` was deleted from PHP for a reason. That code is chock full of scary things. This is doubly ironic because your link at the end recommends against a number of the things that code does.

Comment: Thanks for setting fire to that monstrosity.

Comment: Not sure why `UNIX_TIMESTAMP` factors in here since the `DATE` type column is in [ISO-8601](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_8601) format, `YYYY-MM-DD`, and can be compared as a string as you do in the first example. The second one would work without the `UNIX_TIMESTAMP` part.